# How to fetch sub views / models in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Lets say you have a model "Blog" and a collection (and model) "Posts".

How do you organize backbone code so that you can fetch the url "/blog/:blogID/posts" or "/posts?blog=:blogID"

I am kinda confused on how to structure the code for this. Do you manually need to set the url when making a post list like:

```
Blog = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.posts = new Posts({
      url: '/blogs/' + this.id + '/posts' }) } })
```

Or is there some better way to structure this?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228507/backbone-js-modeling-a-belongs-to-relationship).

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would probably do it.

Backbone doesn't really do much for you in the way of taking care of associations, so you have more <strike>manual work</strike> control when defining your models and how they relate (both in terms of the JavaScript and their URL representations).

Once you define the URL on the collection, all of its contained models will work from that URL, so you really only have to deal with setting the URL when creating the collection.